# How to extend ui from API

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, model-view-controller

My question is about concept (I need some recommendation how to implement it right).
I've use MVC pattern when I build the UI,currently this UI serve two plug-in since the UI they should use are **identical**. so both plugin call to this UI and this is working fine.Now there is third(and four :)) plugins which should use some of the UI control and logic so instead of build new UI for this plugin's I want to provide some mechanism to enable to the user to decide which control he want to draw in the screen. so currently I need to break the view to **sections** but my question is what it the best way to do that ?
(from design and concept aspects)

The view is build from **6 controls** that all the plugin must by default use **two** from them and the rest are optional . for example new plugin can use the mandatory two and provide in addition two more control.

Comment: If I need to add some additional tag please let me know

Comment: Could you show some code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer without knowing the language and platform.

Each of your 6 controls you will have a view and controller. Each view/controller needs a reference to a model that exposes the data and methods appropriate for the view to display and the controller to call. So the question is how to connect up each plugin to the subset of the 6 possible controls.

In your case I would create 6 interfaces that expose the data and methods relevant to each of the 6 controls. Each plugin implements just the interfaces that are possible for that plugin. In addition it would expose a standard interface that all plugins implement. This standard interface would provide a list of the mandatory interfaces it requires shown, as well as the list of optional interfaces it allows to be shown.

Your master view then takes a plugin and asks for the list of mandatory interfaces. It creates those child controls and passed the relevant plugin interface to each of the child controls. It then looks at the optional ones are creates just two of them for display and hooks them up.

Hard to be more precise without more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use MVVM(Model,View,ViewModel) pattern, it's more convenient for shearing code, you can search in google 'MVVM', there are tons of articles about that.